# Conversion from HTML input to String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**User Control (Ascx)**

```
<input type="text" style="width:150px" id="date_range" name="date_range" runat="server" class="form-control daterange-datemenu border-right-0" value="10/18/2019 - 11/23/2019"/>
```

**Codebehind (VB)**

```
Dim dat As String = String.Empty
dat = Request.Form["date_range"].ToString()
```

*Error faced: Value of 'NameValueCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'.*

Comment: Why don't you use a server control (which is how ASP.Net webforms is supposed to be used)?

Comment: Haha, ya. I have changed to use server control rather than input control.

Comment: I talked about `<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDateRange" .... />`, which can be simply accessed from codebehind using `txtDateRange.Text`

Comment: Yay, I get what u mean. Thanks @SteveB

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use like this 
`dat = Request.Form("date_range")`

Comment: For reaching value you should delete runat from user control.<input type="text" style="width:150px" id="date_range" name="date_range" class="form-control daterange-datemenu border-right-0" value="10/18/2019 - 11/23/2019"/>

Comment: Haha thanks. date_range.Value.ToString() can also be used to solve this issue!